# Use SCRAM-SHA-512 authentication with SSL on LoadBalancer in Strimzi Kafka

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-python, strimzi

I am trying to access my Strimzi Kafka Cluster deployed in k8s cluster on AWS (kops not EKS) using kafka-python.

Here's the listener setup:

- I am using an external listener of type loadbalancer
- TLS Encryption is disabled
- Authentication is SCRAM-SHA-512
- I want to access the cluster securely, I cannot provide certificates to the brokers for secure connection. Hence I am using overrides to setup SSL on the LoadBalancers rather than on Kafka side.

Here's the configuration:

```
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.5.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      external:
        port: 9094
        tls: false
        type: loadbalancer
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
        configuration:
          bootstrap:
            host: kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com
          brokers:
          - broker: 0
            host: kafka-broker-0.mydomain.com
          - broker: 1
            host: kafka-broker-1.mydomain.com
          - broker: 2
            host: kafka-broker-2.mydomain.com
        overrides:
          bootstrap:
            address: kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com
            dnsAnnotations:
              # external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:....
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "9094"
          brokers:
          - advertisedHost: kafka-broker-0.mydomain.com
            advertisedPort: 9094
            broker: 0
            dnsAnnotations:
              # external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-broker-0.mydomain.com
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:....
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "9094"
          - advertisedHost: kafka-broker-1.mydomain.com
            advertisedPort: 9094
            broker: 1
            dnsAnnotations:
              # external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-broker-1.mydomain.com
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:....
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "9094"
          - advertisedHost: kafka-broker-2.mydomain.com
            advertisedPort: 9094
            broker: 2
            dnsAnnotations:
              external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-broker-2.mydomain.com
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:....
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "9094"
```

I am able to access the cluster with the following :

- With no authentication (no SCRAM-SHA-512 or any other method for that matter)
- Rest the same as the above configuration (only difference being no authentication)

The client configuration (I am using kafka-python)

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            bootstrap_servers=['kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com:9094'],
            client_id="test-consumer",
            security_protocol="SSL",
            api_version=(2, 5, 0),
        )
```

But I am not able to access the cluster with SCRAM-SHA-512 auth enabled. I get the following error in the python client :

```
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <disconnected> [unspecified None]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <disconnected> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <connecting> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: connecting to kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com [('x.x.x.x', 9094) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com<connecting> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: established TCP connection
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com<connecting> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: initiating SSL handshake
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com<handshake> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: configuring default SSL Context
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com<handshake> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: Loading system default SSL CAs from DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs', openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs')
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <handshake> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: wrapping socket in ssl context
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <handshake> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: completed SSL handshake.
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <handshake> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: initiating SASL authentication
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request SaslHandShakeRequest_v0(mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-512')
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <authenticating> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]> Request 1: SaslHandShakeRequest_v0(mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-512')
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Received correlation id: 1
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Processing response SaslHandShakeResponse_v0
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com<authenticating> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]> Response 1 (220.21484375 ms): SaslHandShakeResponse_v0(error_code=0, enabled_mechanisms=['SCRAM-SHA-512'])
ERROR:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <authenticating> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: Error receiving reply from server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/something/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 692, in _try_authenticate_scram
    (data_len,) = struct.unpack('>i', self._recv_bytes_blocking(4))
  File "/home/something/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 616, in _recv_bytes_blocking
    raise ConnectionError('Connection reset during recv')
ConnectionError: Connection reset during recv
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <authenticating> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: Closing connection. KafkaConnectionError: <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com <authenticating> [IPv4 ('x.x.x.x', 9094)]>: Connection reset during recv
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
```

and this error repeats as the client retries.

This is the python client configuration I am using that generates this error.

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            bootstrap_servers=['kafka-bootstrap.mydomain.com:9094'],
            client_id="test-consumer",
            security_protocol="SASL_SSL",
            api_version=(2, 5, 0),
            sasl_mechanism="SCRAM-SHA-512",
            sasl_plain_username='someusername',
            sasl_plain_password='somerandom'
        )
```

Is this due to some error in the configuration on the Kafka Server/Client side?
I have created a KafkaUser resource in k8s cluster successfully.

Or is it because Kafka needs SSL on the kafka server side (and not on the LoadBalancer side) to make SASL SCRAM-SHA-512 work? If so, is there any work around?

Comment: I never tried it with TLS termination on loadbalancer. I do not see any reason why it should not work. But might be worth trying without it. 

Also, how did you got the username and password? Did you Base64 decode the password? That is a common mistake.

Comment: It worked after I did a base64 decoding. Thank you.